# Class partial template specialization for single function, how to solve undefined error of other members

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I have the following template class. I need to specialize the `alloc` function for some specific `outT` case.

```
template <typename inT, typename outT>
class Filter {
public:

  typedef inT  InputType;
  typedef outT OutputType;

  struct Options {
    int a, b, c;
  };

  virtual void alloc();

};



// Partial template specialization for SpecificOutputType
template < typename inT>
class Filter<inT, SpecificOutputType> {

  virtual void alloc();

};
```

This results in the `Options` class and `OutputType` being undefined for gcc, example:

```
using FilterType = Filter<SomeIn, SpecificOutputType>:
FilterType::Options options;
```

Results in

```
 error: ‘Options’ is not a member of `Filter<SomeIn, SpecificOutputType>`
```

This error does not happen if I use some type other than `SpecificOutputType`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: did you mean `FilterType::Options options;` ?

Comment: Template specialisation doesn't copy all the base template + the edits you want ... you have to put in the entire implementation...

Alternatively you could have a templated base class, say FilterBase, and then the default Filter has no modification, and FilterSpecialisation only needs to override the function(s) you care about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization#Members_of_partial_specializations) is independent, they're irrelevant with the primary template, so you have to also define `Options`, `OutputType` and other necessary members in the template specialization explicitly.

> Members of partial specializations are not related to the members of the primary template.

You could make a common base class template to avoid code duplication.

```
template <typename inT, typename outT>
class FilterBase {
public:

  typedef inT  InputType;
  typedef outT OutputType;

  struct Options {
    int a, b, c;
  };

};

template <typename inT, typename outT>
class Filter : public FilterBase<inT, outT> {
public:
  virtual void alloc();
};


// Partial template specialization for SpecificOutputType
template <typename inT>
class Filter<inT, SpecificOutputType> : public FilterBase<inT, SpecificOutputType> {
  virtual void alloc();
};
```